# Background thread for email sending in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to run a background thread in the Ruby on Rails application that should send an emails when certain date has occurred, depending on the values in DB (and email body should contain some info from this DB).

What is the best way to achieve such behavior?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to run a job at a certain time? (where the job just happens to be an email)

Comment: @user3334690 To be more precise, at a certain condition. Condition in this case is the date that is calculated as "date_in_some_column_of_the_table + 30"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whenever gem to perform background jobs according to your requirement.
Check out the github docs here. [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Ryan Bates created a great Railscast about Whenever: [Cron jobs Intro in rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby)

In config/schedule.rb

```
every 2.hours do 
 runner User.send_email_to_users
end
```

In User model

```
def self.send_email_to_users
  //write your logic here and call to action to send mails.
  UserMailer.send_mail_persons(user).deliver 
  //pass any other data if required in arguments.
end
```

In app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
def send_mail_persons(user)
  @user = user
  mail :to => @user.email, :subject => "Amusement.", :from => MAIL_ADDRESS
```

end

Create a html template as per requirement, app/views/user_mailer/send_mail_persons.html.erb

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether this gem works with Heroku?

Comment: for heroku use the scheduler addon https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler , Detail here https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/11/12/heroku_scheduler_add_on_now_available

Answer (score 4):

You would be better off using a framework like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) than doing it yourself.

With Sidekiq, you can use the Sidekiq Pro or various third-party projects to schedule jobs. See [Recurring jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects) on Sidekiq's wiki for projects that provide scheduling capability.

Answer (score 0):

lib/tasks/mail_task.rake

```
namespace :mail_task do
  desc "Send Mail"
  task :send_mail => :environment do
     ...
  end
end
```

Command line

```
rake mail_task:send_mail
```

Comment: this is background job?